# Wait 5 seconds from starting the form to switching to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wait

I wanted to make a form that displayed an block of text for 5 seconds on the screen before switching to another form. Switching with a button works, but how do I switch after 5 seconds? This is what I have

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UltraPanel
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        private void StartAsyncTimedWork()
        {
            myTimer.Interval = 5000;
            myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(wait);
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        private void wait(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add StartAsyncTimedWork() to constructor Form2() or formloaded method. also in wait () add myTimer.stop();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shown` event of Form2, make it `async`, then `await` your method (here, remaned `StartAsync(int interval)`) from there, passing the delay interval you see fit.

`Form3` is declared with a `using` statement, since `.ShowDialog()` is used: you need to dispose of that Form.
I've added `this.Show()` to show again Form2 when Form3 is closed.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await StartAsync(5000);
}

private async Task StartAsync(int interval)
{
    await Task.Delay(interval);
    this.Hide();
    using (var f3 = new Form3()) {
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }
    this.Show();
}
```

Somewhat more accomplished, in case Form2 can be closed while the delay is in action: if you don't cancel `Task.Delay()`, Form3 would be shown even when Form2 is (apparently) already closed:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = null;

private async void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try {
        await StartAsync(5000, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) {
        // Do whatever you see fit here
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
    }
    finally {
        cts.Dispose();
        cts = null;
    }
}

private async Task StartAsync(int interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(interval, token);
    this.Hide();
    using (var f3 = new Form3()) {
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }
    this.Show();
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cts != null) {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```